# WebForms Unobtrusive Validation Mode

Tags: asp.net, .net

I encountered an error using Regular Expression Validator.

1) Create an ASP.NET Empty application (as WebApplication)
2) Add a Web Form in the WebApplication
3) Add the following line:

inside the `<head></head>`

4) Create a folder "Script", still inside the WebApplication tree
5) Add the jquery-1.8.2.js file inside the folder
6) Inside the div below the form add two textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="A" name="A" type="text" size="50" MaxLength="100" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="B" name="B" type="text" size="50" MaxLength="100" runat="server" />
```

7) For each textbox add a RegularExpressionValidator, so the code would be:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="A" name="A" type="text" size="50" MaxLength="100" runat="server" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                ValidationGroup="alpha" ID="ControlA"
                runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="A" 
                ValidationExpression=".{10}">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:TextBox ID="B" name="B" type="text" size="50" MaxLength="100" runat="server" />        
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                ValidationGroup="beta" ID="ControlB"
                runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="B" 
                ValidationExpression=".{2}">
```

8) create a button below the text boxes:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

9) In the button method "Button_click" create a string to check if it works:
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = A.Text + " " + B.Text;
        }

10) run the program.

11) any error like:
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

My version of VS is: 12.0.30501.00 Update 2.
.NET Framework: 4.5.51641
I tried with IE and Chrome, with jquery-1.8.2.js and jquery-2.1.1.js
Windows 8.1 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line in your `web.config` :

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
```

Or add this line on your `web.config` :

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

Or in your `global.asax` :

```
ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None
```

Comment: Please do explain your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET 4.5 and later has unobtrusive validation which controls the client side validation.
In your web.config

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
```

This means that unobtrusive validation is on and will use jQuery...which you can add by:

```
Clicking Tools->NewGet Package Manager->Manage NuGet Packages For Solution...
Click on Browse and Search for "aspnet.scriptmanager.jquery"
```

or leave it off (the old way which uses script elements in HTML for validation via JavaScript)

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

The benefit of having it on is that it reduces the amount of JavaScript that has to be generated.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it shows how enable the unobstrusive validation, and not only disable it. Also explains what it means. Upvoted.